# Blender 3D 2.78b on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 - CUDA error at cuCtxCreate:

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am experiencing CUDA crashes on Blender 2.78b.

The error given is the following:

> CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Launch failed.

[image: Cuda error]

It only happens with 2.78b, I've tried both 2.78 and 2.78a and there CUDA works correctly.

I am using clean versions, without changing any settings/installed addons.

The scene consists of the default cube, a single light and a camera and the Feature Set is set to 'Supported'.

The graphics card I am using is - NVidia GeForce GTX 780M 4096 MB, I also have the latest CUDA version installed, see screenshot below.

[image]

More info regarding the system, see below.

[image]

Has anyone experienced CUDA issues with Blender 2.78b? I noticed that this version moved to CUDA 8.0, which I am now using.

Comment: Had this problem earlier today.. just had to restart my computer. I'm sure you've already tried that buy you never know

Comment: I did so indeed.. :(